# Windows RT IE10 vs Windows 8 IE10

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, windows-rt

What is the difference between IE10 on Windows RT and IE10 on Windows 8? Is the IE10 on both the platform has same HTML, CSS and Script engine?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same browser. The main difference is the User Agent string. On Windows RT the architecture token is "Arm", while on Windows it is either absent, "WOW64" or "Win64; x64":
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/12/ie10-user-agent-string-update.aspx

You can see on sites like HTML5test that Windows RT and Windows 8 browsers have the same score.